# Повернуть на или в?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какие из следующих выражений лучше употреблять при объяснении другому человеку верного направления на улице?

Повернуть на улицу.
Повернуть в улицу. 
Повернуть в переулок. 
Повернуть на переулок.

Почему в число вариантов включил вариант с предлогом "на"? Потому что наличие прилагательного в составе названия улицы побуждает употребить его.

Повернуть на Большой Ордынский переулок. Повернуть на Поварскую улицу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С "**улицей**" предлог "**в**" сочетается разве что в выражении "***упереться в*** такую-то улицу" и привносится из устойчивого сочетания "**упереться в**о что-либо". В сочетании с "улицей" при "сворачивании" возможны предлоги "**на**" (свернуть на улицу такую-то - если движение продолжается уже по этой улице) и "**к**" (если сворачивают *в направлении* указанной улицы, двигаясь по какому-либо иному пути). С "**переулком**" совсем иначе: основное употребление имеет предлог "**в**" (*свернуть в переулок*). Вероятно, это потому, что (типично узкий, тёмный) переулок мыслится как относительно замкнутое пространство по сравнению с (открытой, светлой в дневное время) улицей (**на улице**, но **в переулке**). В обоих случаях (в сочетании с *улицей* или *переулком*) предпочтительно "**свернул**" (=с прежнего пути, дороги), а "**повернул**" (относительно прежнего *направления движения* - оно может быть и в поле) лучше сочетается с указанием *направления, стороны* (пошёл по пустырю, затем повернул направо, в сторону собора и т. п.)

Answer (score 1):

Свернуть (с улицы) на улицу.

Завернуть в переулок.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/завернуть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C) (есть данный пример)

Повернуть налево.